# CGAL: convert quotient to double

Tags: c++, cgal

I am having a problem in converting CGAL QP solver

```
typedef CGAL::Gmpzf ET;
...define a quadratic program qp here...
Solution s = CGAL::solve_quadratic_program(qp, ET());
assert (s.solves_quadratic_program(qp));
cout<<"QP objective = "<<s.objective_value()<<endl;
// The above returns a value of type CGAL::Quotient<ET>
// and I need to convert it to double
double n = s.objective_value_numerator().to_double();
double d = s.objective_value_denominator().to_double();
cout<<"QP objective 2 = "<<n/d<<endl;
```

I got:

```
QP objective = -2.57497e-22/2.01459e-22 
QP objective 2 = -nan
```

I checked and observed that `n = -inf` and `d = inf`.

How do we properly convert a Quotient into double?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion!!

Comment: `CGAL::to_double(x)` http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Number_types/classCGAL_1_1Quotient.html#a4eda6b19dcdfb5a9735531d338c8f721

Comment: @MarcGlisse: That answered my question. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGAL has a function [`CGAL::to_double`](http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#to_double) that can be used on [most number types](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Algebraic_foundations/group__PkgAlgebraicFoundations.html#ga1f1bcd74fce34fd532445590bbda5cd5) and in particular [on Quotient](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Number_types/classCGAL_1_1Quotient.html#a4eda6b19dcdfb5a9735531d338c8f721). It has [special code](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/39f1c4f589b16114b08a88464ea9d1ff7a80d943/Number_types/include/CGAL/Quotient.h#L699) exactly for this case where numerator and denominator would overflow. It does **not** have code for underflow, which cannot happen with a quotient of integers, but could happen with Gmpzf, yielding `0/0`.